# Respuesta de http.get en Scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

Estoy escribiendo un controlador en AngularJS que hace un llamado por http.get a una API, y devuelve un 0 (por ahora). Logro mostrar el 0 por consola sin problemas, pero no puedo mostrarlo en un $scope en el front.

**App.js**

```
   .controller('ssnGenAltaCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
    function($scope, $http){
        $scope.data = {};
        $scope.generarRubricaAlta = function(data){
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'url'
            }).then(function successCallback(data) {
                console.log(data.data);
                $scope.data.mensaje = data.data;
            }, function errorCallback(data) {
                console.log("Error");
            });
        }
    }]);
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button" ng-click="generarRubricaAlta()">Generar Rubrica Alta</a>
    <p class="bg-primary">{{data.mensaje}}</p>
</div>
```

**Ruteo**

```
.when("/ssnGenAlta", {
    templateUrl : "views/ssnGenAlta.html",
    controller: "ssnGenAltaCtrl"
})
```

El controller lo tengo declarado en el ruteo. No me está dando ningún error ahora mismo por consola, pero al hacer click en el botón me muestra el 0 devuelto por consola pero no en el front.

Comment: Prueba cambiar $scope.data.mensaje por $scope.mensaje

Comment: y en el html {{mensaje}}

Comment: Acabo de probar y no funcionó. Tampoco me muestra ningún error en la consola. No se si tenga que ver, pero estoy utilizando ng-view para manejar las vistas. Lo comento porque al hacer click en el botón, el mismo desaparece, cosa que me parece raro.

Comment: Es un problema con el ng-view. Metí todo en el index y funciona... lo que no entiendo es por qué me da problemas con eso. En index.html tengo un navbar y un div copn ng-view. Las vistas me las muestra bien, y se rutea bien. Pero cuando dentro de una vista presiono un botón, el mismo desaparece y el resultado del $scope no aparece.

Comment: Creo que si al hacer get traes la pagina y te recarga por ende el scope ya no es el mismo

Comment: @TomasPichierri puedes agregar el html completo de tu vista?

Comment: @sioesi el html completo de la vista es el que está en la publicación. Luego tengo un index.html que tiene un <div ng-view></div>.

Comment: y donde le dices a que controlador pertenece? en el index tiene el ng-app?

Comment: En el index tengo el ng-app y en el app.js tengo el controller en el ruteo. Lo dejo en el post.

Answer (score 0):

Puede que estos dos links te sean de ayuda (misma web):

https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/#controllers-as-classes

y

https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/#nested-scopes

Si no te funciona, tengo otras dos opciones, cada cual más densa..

**Opción 1:**

*Generar una variable al entrar en el controlador*

```
angular.module('aplicativo').controller('MainCtrl', function ()
{
    var main = this;
    ...
```

*y utilizar esta variable como scope*

```
$http({
   method  : 'POST',
   url     : 'url',
   data    : 'data'
})
.success(function(data){
     main.user = 'Pepito';
 })
 .error(function() {
     console.error('ERROR!');
  });
```

*y en la vista:*

```
    <div>{{main.user}}</div>
```

**Opción 2:**

En la respuesta AJAX, una función callback, algo como:

*función en el controlador:*

```
$scope.getAct(
    function (data) {
          console.log(data)
    }
);
```

*función de llamada AJAX:*

```
$scope.getAct = function(functionCallback)
{

   $http({
      method  : 'POST',
      url     : 'url',
      data    : 'data'
   })
   .success(function(data){
        functionCallback(data);
   })
   .error(function() {
        console.error('ERROR!');
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

¿Por casualidad en el config de la aplicación tienes un interceptor de http?
Algo como lo siguiente:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function () {

});
```

En el cual estés interceptando los response y no los estés devolviendo adecuadamente?

Comment: Hola @AlejoTamayo. Te comento que esto no es un foro. El lugar donde publicaste es exclusivamente para respuestas que no requieran aclaración del autor, Una vez que tengas la suficiente reputación, podrás dejar comentarios. Mientras tanto, te invito a realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].